# How to correctly format date with timezone in date-fns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, date-fns

I am using date-fns library but It is not formatting the date correctly.

My code:

```
    import { format } from 'date-fns'
    console.log(format(endOfDay(new Date()), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"))
```

Required result:

```
      2022-05-19T23:59:59Z
```

Actual result:

```
      2022-05-19T23:59:59+02
```

Please help me in finding the mistake. Thank you

Comment: If you don't need timezone, just remove it from format - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" //2022-05-19T23:59:59

Comment: @WillBlack I need timezone

Comment: I see only 'Z' at the end of string in "Required result". If you need letter Z you can add it like this: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'". What timezone display format do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired result using format...

```
import { format } from 'date-fns'

console.log(format(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
```

Comment: formatISO(new Date()) is giving the same result. I need Z at the end

Comment: i think that in this way you are losing the timezone in the final date. from the example of the question you would lose 2 hours